# How to see all the apps I have downloaded from Google Play store?

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Is it possible to see all apps I've downloaded on the Google Play store?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to see all Google Play Store apps you've downloaded.

**On your Android device:**

**1)** Open Google Play Store app

**2)** Tap the hamburger menu in the top left corner
[image: GooglePlay1]

**3)** Inside the menu, tap "My apps & games"
[image: GooglePlay2]

**4)** You will get a list of all the apps you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Current url to list online all installed Google Play apps is https://play.google.com/apps. There is option to filter by devices.

List of recently uninstalled apps: https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=ogoXCAYSC0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OKgIIAVICCAM%3D:S:ANO1ljJeyws&gsr=ChqiChcIBhILQVBQTElDQVRJT04qAggBUgIIAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljLsirA

List of recently uninstalled games: https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=ogoQCAYSBEdBTUUqAggBUgIIAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKj8QE&gsr=ChOiChAIBhIER0FNRSoCCAFSAggD:S:ANO1ljL_xzM

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Google Play Store.
2. Swipe from the left edge of the screen to the right (to reveal a menu).
3. Select "My apps & games"
4. The "Installed" tab shows all apps currently installed while the "All" tab shows all apps you ever installed including removed apps.

Note: The names could be slighty different since my play store app is not in English.

Comment: Thanx. Seems as if I were  over thinking it.lol

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to see all the apps you have installed in your android device using either the Google Playstore App or using the web interface of google on your PC using this link https://play.google.com/store?hl=en. Remember when using the WEB you need to sign in with the same google account as that in your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled *Google Activity*, you can do below

Go to https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity

On left side pane select *Other Google activity*

Under  Google Play library, select *View Activity*